# Issue While getting the selectedIndex from Dijit/form/Select

Tags: dojo

I am working on the upgrade of Dojo from 1.4 to 1.8 on a jsp page.Below is code snippet

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" gutters="false"
                            style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px">
                            <select name="<%=inputName%>"
                                id="XX.AddNewDocument.<%=panelName%>.<%=inputName%>"
                                jsId="XX.AddNewDocument.<%=panelName%>.<%=inputName%>"
                                onKeyPress="handleSearchPanelInputKeyDown"
                                onBlur="handleSearchPanelInputLostFocus"
                                onFocus="handleSearchPanelInputGetFocus"
                                onChange="onChangeLinkedField(this)"
                                <%
            String dataSourceUrl = inputConfig.getPicklistUrl();
                                        System.out.println("Jaya6 dataSourceUrl "+dataSourceUrl);
            boolean hasDataSource = dataSourceUrl != null && dataSourceUrl.length() > 0;
            if (hasDataSource) {
                %>
                                store="<%=uiModel.getInputDataStoreId(panelName, inputName)%>"
                                <%
            }
            if (inputConfig.isHidden()) {
                %>
                                style="visibility: hidden;" <%
            }
                %>
                                data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" inputWidth="168" 
                                style="width:186px;margin:2px;" maxHeight="200"
                                sortByLabel=true>
                                <%
```

on the "onChange" event onChangeLinkedField function is called in another JSP :

```
this.onChangeLinkedField = function (srcField) {

    alert(srcField.selectedIndex);
     console.log(srcField.name + " changed by user");
    this.changeLinkedField(srcField);
}
```

but srcField.selectedIndex is returning null. I want to get the Index of Selected value

Please help to get the same

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you try to console srcField to see what it return on selection either a value or an object?

Comment: srcField is returning the Value selected from dijit/form/Select

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this replace

```
this.onChangeLinkedField = function (srcField) {

    this.store.get(srcField).then(
       function(response){
            console.log(response); // result object{} contain id and data
    });
    this.changeLinkedField(srcField);
}
```

I hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.
I am getting the store as undefined
Above mentioned codes are in different files

Comment: Mithlesh, can you please provide the solution?

Comment: Hey I not familiar with Java so I didn't understand how data is populated in select box. To connect data to store of `dijit/form/Select` you need either `dojo/store/Memory` or `dojo/store/JsonRest`.
Alternative is you just try what `this.options` gives you.

Comment: this.options is undefined.
But this code was working in dojo 1.4

Comment: srcField.options is 4 objects (may be because there are 4 values currently

Comment: Yes srcField.options provide you an array of all options of select box. Have you tried what srcField.store return?